# Auto populate a text field based on another text field (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, input

I am trying to auto-populate a text field based on the value of another input field.

The difference between other questions made in Stack Overflow, is:

- PHP or JavaScript scripting language.
- The auto populated field should be without accents (áéíóúñ), all characters must be in lowercase and separated with dashes.

As showed in this picture:
[image: Input field one (Titulo) and input field two (Titulo Alias)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('#titulo').keyup(function() {
        var replacements = {"á":"a", "é":"e", "í":"i", "ó":"o", "ú":"u", "ñ":"n", " ":"-"};
        val = $('#titulo').val().toLowerCase().split('');
        $.each(val, function(i,e){val[i] = replacements[e] ? replacements[e] : e;});
        $('#titulo-alias').val(val.join(''));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#titulo-alias').val( $('#titulo').val().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-') );`

To remove accents take a look at [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#titulo-alias').val( $('#titulo').val().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-').replace('á', 'a').replace('é', 'e').replace('í', 'i').replace('ó', 'o').replace('ú', 'u').replace('ñ', 'n') );
```

Comment: Sorry for the late responce. I havent really test this code before posting. Im on a rush that day. Anyway glad that your problem is solve. cheers!